# Why does gcc return 0 instead of the address of a stack allocated variable?

Tags: c, gcc

As part of an experiment using custom stacks, I wanted a function to return the address of a stack allocated char buffer.

```
// return pointer to stack variable
void *foo(void)
{
    char sz[10] = "hello";
    return sz;
}
```

I know that it's illegal to do this in C, and gcc warns too.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fomit-frame-pointer -O0 -c foo.c 

foo.c:8:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return sz;
```

Still, since this is part of an experiment, I want the code as is. The funny thing is that the generated code returns 0 instead of sz's stack address:

```
boa@localhost:~/tmp$ objdump -dMintel foo.o
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   48 b8 68 65 6c 6c 6f    movabs rax,0x6f6c6c6568
   7:   00 00 00 
   a:   48 89 44 24 f0          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10],rax
   f:   66 c7 44 24 f8 00 00    mov    WORD PTR [rsp-0x8],0x0
  16:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  1b:   c3                      ret
```

As one can see, 0x0 is moved to eax, which is what puzzles me. Why does gcc do this?

Here's a complete source file with another function, bar(), as well as a main function. bar() returns the address as expected.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// return pointer to stack variable
void *foo(void)
{
    char sz[10] = "hello";
    return sz;
}

void *bar(void)
{
    char sz[10] = "hello";
    intptr_t i = (intptr_t)sz;
    return (void*)i;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("foo: %p\n", foo());
    printf("bar: %p\n", bar());
    return 0;
}

boa@localhost:~/tmp$ make foo && ./foo
cc   foo.o   -o foo
foo: (nil)
bar: 0x7ffce518a268
```

This is a mystery to me. What may be the logic behind gcc's choice?

Comment: Because it is optimized out.

Comment: @EugeneSh. AFAICT it's not optimized out. The stack variable is initialized with "hello" and then zero-terminated, as expected. Also, -O0 was used to compile foo.c.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? Under gcc 4.9.2, I get `lea rax, [rsp-0x10]` as the fourth instruction, not the `mov` you're seeing.

Comment: @duskwuff gcc version 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-2) (GCC), binutils 2.26.1-1, on Fedora 24

Comment: I have seen comments somewhere, that `NULL` is returned so that dereferencing the pointer will fail predictably and not erratically.

Comment: Assuming the behavior is deliberate (it may not be), you'd need to ask gcc's developers why they chose it.  The thing about undefined behavior is that *any* result is allowed, and the result doesn't have to be consistent.

Comment: Does `bar` also generate a compiler warning? Perhaps you obfuscate just enough to fool it.

Comment: I hope you've considered the possibility that an interrupt routine will step on that part of the stack before you have a chance to use it.

Comment: @user3386109 The experiment was to use a custom stack with a POSIX thread, and -- within that thread -- be able to read the stack after a function call. It was part of an attempt to answer a question I came across on this site.

Comment: Yes, I saw that question too. And last I saw, the OP had been convinced that what s/he was proposing was a bad idea. And the clincher was the interrupt. Interrupts can happen in any thread.

Comment: Returning pointers to local variables: this smells like UB (undefined behaviour).

Comment: @WeatherVane Good question. bar() compiles without warnings with -O0, but with warnings with -O3. The generated code still works as expected for bar(), foo() still fails.

Comment: I find it is a good feature of gcc. At least you get consistent failures. 
After all, the compiler can reliably know you are returning something from the soon-to-be-smashed stack.

Answer (score 6):

GCC deliberately returns `NULL` in this case as can be seen from the [code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bc35ef6543424134df1619909df728a52d6f1f7f/gcc/gimple-ssa-isolate-paths.c#L556):

```
tree zero = build_zero_cst (TREE_TYPE (val));
gimple_return_set_retval (return_stmt, zero);
update_stmt (stmt);
```

Newer versions of GCC and Clang exploit undefined behavior more aggressively so this check is not suprising. It also makes code fail fast which is a good thing in most cases (not yours, apparently).