# Functions returning pointers not printing correctly

Tags: function, pointers

When I run the program shown below, it prints the address correctly inside the function (fun), but outside the function is always prints zero

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *fun();
main()
{
    int *p;

    printf("\n %u", p);
    p = fun();
    printf("\n %u", fun());
}

int *fun()
{
    int i = 20;
    printf("\n %u", &i);
    return (&i);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does gcc return 0 instead of the address of a stack allocated variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290049/why-does-gcc-return-0-instead-of-the-address-of-a-stack-allocated-variable)

Comment: The first `printf` in `main` is 0 cause the variable is not initialized. Looks like the compiler initializes it to 0.